# RSS/Atom feed of Subversion commit comments

Tags: svn, rss, comments, atom-feed

We have recently introduced version control in Subversion in our development cycle, and a team mate asked me today if it was possible to get all commit comments in an RSS feed. Since I think it's a pretty cool idea, I looked around in the Visual SVN Server option windows, and here on SO, but couldn't find anything relevant. (Most searches on anything with RSS in it here turns to discussions/questions regarding the format itself... unless you have infinite search-fu, which I don't.)

So, **is there some (easy) way to publish SVN commit comments in a feed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate an RSS feed with Subversion commits you will need to use a server side application, the simplest one I've come across is PyRSS2Gen (a simple Perl application); http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html and theres a nice tutorial on how to go about using it here: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2006/08/17/howto-adding-an-rss-feed-to-a-subversion-server/

Comment: It turns out we already had support for exactly what we wanted in TeamCity, which we also use. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As a roundabout way you can set up [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) and it provides an RSS feed.

You could also build your own on top of one of the binding libraries quite easily I guess.

Comment: It turns out we already had support for exactly what we wanted in TeamCity, which we also use. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want notifications about commits (not necessarily an RSS feed), you could use [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor). That tool notifies you of new commits and has a very low memory footprint.